# Expressing "more and more"

Tags: word-usage

So I see different forms in Korean to express the meaning "more and more", for instance:

더욱더 풍성해졌습니다 -> become more and more thrive.

더욱더, 더더욱, 더욱, 더욱이, 더욱더욱 seemed to be expressing the same thing. How can I determine when to use which or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I think they are mostly equivalent in general, though 더더욱 and 더욱더 might express more emphasis (still not a real difference.) I don't think 더욱더욱 is used.

Comment: "More and more" is an English language phrase I hear Koreans use more than native English speakers. I wonder what Korean ESL textbooks translated as "more and more..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make Korean SE a sole 100% answered site on Stack Exchange, this question needs answering.

They don't mean the same thing at all.

The adverbs '[더](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=9437800)' and '[더욱](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=9475100)' are synonymous meaning:

> 정도나 수준 따위가 한층 심하거나 높게. (Literally) More or higher in degree or level.

They all can be translated to 'more' in English.

However, '[더욱이](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=9475400)' has a different meaning:

> 그러한 데다가 더. (Literally) In addition to what has been mentioned.

You can't use '더욱이' in place of '더' and '더욱'.

As @krim mentioned, '[더더욱](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=9447000)' and '[더욱더](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=9475200)' are used to emphasize '더욱' and they mean:

> ‘더욱’을 강조하여 이르는 말. A word emphasizing '더욱'.

The word '[더욱더욱](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=9475300)' could be different from 더, 더욱, 더더욱, 더욱더 as its focus is on progress.

Which one to use will depend on what you try to mean.

Comment: "In order to make Korean SE a sole 100% answered site on Stack Exchange" - a laudable goal. Do you know if closed questions count towards those stats?